# Has connect 4 in 3D been studied in CS?

Tags: reference-request, board-games

Connect 4 is a classical game in computer science. Recently I found a web game where one could play the game on a 3d board. One version can be found here

https://www.mathsisfun.com/games/connect3d.html

[image]

I know Connect 4 has been completed, and developed algorothms for solving it. Like the minmax strategy.

[Algorithms for Connect 4?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18012/algorithms-for-connect-4)

**My question is: Is there written any articles / done research on connect 4 in 3D before?** Has there been developed any algorithms etc?

Comment: Use Google Scholar.

Comment: It's called "Score Four".

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find anything on that particular game, but I found an analysis of a similar game called qubic in Victor Allis' PhD thesis chapter 4: http://fragrieu.free.fr/SearchingForSolutions.pdf

It is essentially Connect 4 in 3D without gravity.